# Vector equation for the intersection of a cylinder and plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have the plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ given by $x+y=1$, and we have the cylinder given by $y^2+z^2=4$. Write the intersection in vector equation.

My thoughts.

Not sure if my professor told us how to do this, he probably didn't and will probably teach this today, but I want to be safe for the quiz. I know I can solve for $y$ from the equation of the plane to get $y=1-x$ and set this equal to the $y$ in the equation of the cylinder to get:

$$y^2+z^2=(1-x)^2+z^2=4$$

However I'm not exactly sure how use this to get a vector equation. Also is "a vector equation" referring to $r(t)=<f(t),g(t),h(t)>$?

Comment: **HINT**: How do you parametrize $(y,z)$ satisfying $y^2+z^2=4$? Yes, you want them both in terms of $t$.

Comment: $y=2\sin t$ and $z=2\cos t$ ? Hence $r(t)=<x,2\sin t,2\cos t>$ also if that is right can I say that for $x+y=1$ we have $r(s)=<s,1-s,z>$. Then what can I do with that?

Comment: But $x=1-y$, so put in what you have for $y$ !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a little sketch, you will be convinced that the intersection you are looking for is a closed curve that is an ellipse. How is it possible to parameterize an ellipse ? By using trigonometric functions. Because the cylinder has radius 2, a natural parametrization is

$$\cases{y=2\cos(\theta)\\z=2\sin(\theta)}$$

for a unique $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$. As a consequence, there is a unique way to express $x$, i.e., $x=1-y=1-2\cos(\theta).$

Thus a parametrization of this ellipse is $(x,y,z)=(1-2\cos(\theta),2\cos(\theta),2\sin(\theta)).$

(Note that I have said: "a parameterization", and not "the parameterization" because there is an infinity of different parameterizations of a curve).